# Архитектура/структура базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, архитектура

Есть такая схема:

- У системы множество пользователей
- У каждого пользователя есть больше одного "TODO" списка дел
- У каждого списка, понятное дело, есть "дела", которые нужно сделать, а их, в свою очередь, можно отмечать как сделанные

У меня пока идеи такие

1 таблица:

```
[User]
id, name, pass...
```

2 таблица:

```
[List]
id(int), user_id(int), name(varchar), description(varchar)
```

3 таблица:

```
[Task]
id(int), list_id(int), text(varchar), done(bool)
```

**ВОПРОС:**
Как упростить схему данных, чтобы потом не пришлось мучатся с написанием логики?

Comment: А задачи [Task] типовые или каждый раз-что то новое?

Comment: Оставляйте как есть. Как вариант - добавить три поля со временем: когда задача добавлена, когда дедлайн и когда решена. Тогда поле done можно убрать.

Comment: Да, нормально выглядит схема.

Comment: Похоже, что схему надо усложнять, а не упрощать. Плановое время завершения задачи. Фактическое время. Даты последнего изменения. Наверняка у задачи могут быть подзадачи или просто зависимость. Так же кажется очень важным приоритет задач. Это уже не говоря о комментариях и заметках)

Answer (score 1):

Если строго решили использовать реляционную модель, то вроде норм. Но представьте, если вам вдруг надо получить доступ к "делу" в каком-то списке, а у вас есть только user_id, то надо будет делать 2 запроса или join, что может начать напрягать со временем вашу базу.
Поэтому я использовал бы здесь частично нереляционную модель и какую-нибудь nosql базу.
Сделал бы я это примерно таким способом:

- юзеров бы хранил в отдельной табличке, как у вас уже и написано
- списки и дела хранил бы в виде кортежей [user_id, todo_list_id, {json}] в нереляционной бд
- один список - это один кортеж
- индексы надо иметь по user_id и по user_id+todo_list_id
- сами дела сразу же оформлял бы в виде джейсона, чтобы было удобно расширять/изменять

Comment: С другой стороны, если дел может быть "бесконечно" много, то такая схема в лоб тоже "не блещет". Но все же можно подумать в эту сторону.